# C++ testing framework: recommendation sought

Tags: c++, windows, unit-testing, frameworks

I'm looking for a "quick and dirty" C++ testing framework I can use on my Windows/Visual Studio box. It's just me developing, so it doesn't have to be enterprise class software. 
Staring at a list of testing frameworks, I am somewhat befuddled...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks#C.2B.2B

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here's a great article about C++ TDD frameworks](http://www.gamesfromwithin.com/articles/0412/000061.html).  For the record, my personal preference is CxxTest, which I have been happily using for about six months now.

Comment: link updated: http://gamesfromwithin.com/exploring-the-c-unit-testing-framework-jungle

Answer (score 5):

I have used both [UnitTest++](http://unittest-cpp.sourceforge.net/) and [Boost.Test](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/test/doc/html/index.html). They are both easy to setup and use.
Although, I wouldn't use Boost.Test if you're not already using the Boost libraries. It's a bit much to install all of Boost just to get the testing framework.

Answer (score 5):

Great question! There have already been a few questions that address

A few:

- [Unit testing for C++ code - Tools and methodology](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91384/unit-testing-for-c-code-tools-and-methodology)
- [C++ unit testing framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87794/c-unit-testing-framework)
- [Unit Testing C Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65820/unit-testing-c-code)

Answer (score 4):

Also take a look at [Google Test](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/primer.md), Google's C++ test framework.

Answer (score 1):

I use [UnitTest++](http://unittest-cpp.sourceforge.net/) and [AMOP](http://code.google.com/p/amop/) for the Mock objects.

However now I would take a long hard look at [GoogleTest](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/) and [GoogleMock](http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/) as they would probably complement each other quite well.

Comment: I was using UnitTest++ and hippomocks, and I took a look at GoogleTest and GoogleMock, and I can say that my current tools are a lot simpler.

Comment: Is that due to them being related? I have used UnitTest++ (and still do on older projects) and can't imagine anything being simpler than UT++. Is HippoMocks difficult?

Comment: No they aren't related. They are both really simple to use.

Answer (score 0):

To get a bare bones testing suite going, I recommend the include-only "Fructose". It is especially neat if you want your tests to run on platforms where text output requires calling non-standard APIs (think gaming consoles, embedded devices etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [CUnitWin32](http://code.google.com/p/cunitwin32/). It includes an example.