# unit test in c++

Tags: c++, unit-testing

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [C++ testing framework: recommendation sought](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185050/c-testing-framework-recommendation-sought)
>   [C++ unit testing framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87794/c-unit-testing-framework)

Hello,

which unit test framework do you recommend for c++ ?

Thanks

Comment: This is just one of many similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[unit-testing]+[c%2B%2B]+framework

Comment: ALL THE precedent post are not very pertinent that's why I repost

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the past I was using CppUnit(http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/cppunit/index.php?title=Main_Page), but now I prefer the Boost test library (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/test/doc/html/index.html).

Lately I also use QTest (part of the Qt framework) also for my non-Qt projects (http://qt.nokia.com/products/)

Answer (score 2):

google test  http://code.google.com/p/googletest/

Answer (score 2):

Unittest++ : http://unittest-cpp.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

See this,

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_0/libs/test/doc/index.html

Boost Test Library