# How to write a code generator given a custom IDL?

Tags: c++, code-generation, idl

If you have a simple enough schema with basic boolean string fields, how to go about writing a code generator in C++. 
If you ever wrote , how did you start. Articles/recommendation welcome.

EDIT: Note that this is not the standard CORBA idl.

Comment: What are you trying to generate? If you say 'IDL' I think 'CORBA'. Why do not use a existing generator/CORBA compiler?

Comment: Badly posed question. Why don't you rephrase?

Comment: Edited based on comments

Comment: An example of schema would probably help get more responses.

Answer (score 1):

In summary:

1. Convert something by hand,
2. copy that output into a string literal and then
3. generalise with loops and variables instead of fixed names.

This is a particularly good problem to tackle with TDD - start by setting up a framework such as CPPUnit (or [one of many alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387272/unit-testing-in-c)) with *stupidly simple* tests that just ensure you can load a file and iterate its contents by writing them out.

Approach the solution very incrementally - get something simple and general output, with a test to confirm it works, then add a more sophisticated variation. eg: handle single parameter functions first.

For code up to a moderate range of complexity, just have a long set of output statements using the standard C++ ostream classes which will allow you to write lots of code mixing literals with any variables.

Answer (score 0):

[Comet](http://www.lambdasoft.dk/comet/index.htm) is pretty good library to implement COM.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your question lacks details about what exactly you are trying to generate. However I will take a stab and recommend that you look at the C++ boost library spirit (http://spirit.sourceforge.net). With Spirit you can create parsers. So assuming you have written a spirit parser for your DSL (domain specific language - your IDL) you will get an AST (abstract syntax tree) after parsing your IDL file(s) that you can walk with the visitor pattern and by creating appropriate visitors you can generate whatever output you need, e.g. generating code.