# Unit testing in C++

Tags: c++, unit-testing, qt, tdd, qt-creator

I've been reading a lot about Unit tests and Test Driven developemnt.

Recently, I also read java unit test code.

I however, prefer to develop in Qt. So I googled up "unit testing in c++" and found a host of information about various unit testing frameworks available for C++.

However, I could not find a reliable comparison of the the various frameworks.

So I look to the SO community to guide me through the selection of what may the "best" unit testing framework for c++.

Also, if anybody had specific comments regarding TDD in Qt (especially using Qt-Creator), then they are more than welcome.

Comment: Search SO - multiple questions exist for this topic. Voting to close.

Comment: Oh, but none of them touch the Qt aspect.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Usually use [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/test/doc/html/intro.html), but if you are using Qt, their [QtTestLib](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qttestlib/qtest-overview.html) might be the better choice.

Comment: just what I was looking for :)

Comment: I dont know about Boost so much but the biggest downside of QTestLib is that it isnt reliable with crashes - eg if your unit crashes, your whole suite crashes and then the report will be hard to parse (if you rely on that feature, for example in automatic test reporting).

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend [doctest](https://github.com/onqtam/doctest) (created by me) - it's the lightest on compile times from all the popular testing frameworks. It is also a direct competitor to [Catch](https://github.com/philsquared/Catch) which is currently the most used framework - checkout the differences in the [FAQ](https://github.com/onqtam/doctest/blob/master/doc/markdown/faq.md#how-is-doctest-different-from-catch)

Answer (score 3):

This seems too be the same question as:

[Unit testing in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387272/unit-testing-in-c) which is actually c++ despite the URL title.

From there, they link to two more SO questions which should help:

[Unit testing for C++ code - Tools and methodology](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91384/unit-testing-for-c-code-tools-and-methodology)
[C++ unit testing framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87794/c-unit-testing-framework)

Answer (score 3):

There is a [table comparing all (?) the C++ unit test frameworks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks#C.2B.2B) available from wikipedia.

There also is an old [comparison of C++ unit test frameworks](http://gamesfromwithin.com/?p=29) available. I do not think it has not been updated so I mention it as a complement as it's more argumented than the table. It covers, CppUnit, CppUnitLite, Boost.Test, NanoCppUnit, Unit++, CxxTest, especially it does not cover [Google C++ framework](http://code.google.com/p/googletest).

Comment: Boost.Test at least has been heavily extended and improved since the gamesfromwithin article was written. The same is probably true for the other frameworks as well, but I don't use those, so can't say for sure.

Answer (score 2):

The "xUnit" family of testing frameworks is usually pretty solid (jUnit, NUnit, etc.).  I haven't used it myself, but there is a port of jUnit for C++:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/cppunit

Comment: cppUnit is very easy to use and run - we use it in a commercial environment, testing over 50 separate Dlls, each with a few thousand test cases. It's proven to be very reliable and flexible.

Answer (score 1):

[Boost](http://www.boost.org/) is usually a good choice, and it contains a testing framework, the [Boost Test Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/test/doc/html/index.html). I have used it for small test cases and it did what I expected, but I haven't used it extensively like in TTD.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get off the ground quickly without figuring out how to build a library, there is a single header file include solution, which supports fixtures (setup and teardown), the usual TEST() {} with CHECK_TRUE, etc.
It also has memory leak detection and performance testing capabilities.

https://gitlab.com/cppocl/unit_test_framework