# State of the art C++ Unit Testing?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, cross-platform

What are the most modern approaches to *unit testing* for the C++ language? The class of the languages with bigger introspection power (like Python) have unit testing frameworks that are somehow more natural to use. Unit tests can be defined more easily. In comparison, the classical `CppUnit` (based on  `JUnit`) seems to take very conservative approach. Is there anything newer and better that uses the specific power of C++ (or even C++11) to make the life easier?

I have been using `CppUnit` framework for a while in rather simplistic way for parts of the project on Windows native C++ (Visual Studio 2005 and 2010). We did not choose the Test Driven Development approach earlier, because there already was a lot of legacy code, and we had found it quite difficult to add tests for it. We had to refactor the application, but adding all the nice tests would be time consuming even in the case.

Recently, we have switched to Visual Studio 2013 (because of the C++11 standard implementation), and we are going to start new, rather long-term project.

Having the previous good (small) experience with unit testing, I would like to try the Test Driven Development approach. As the project is not a tiny one (expected size about the same as the older one, i.e. about 200 k lines of code), I prefer rather more easy (but not less capable) framework.

There is a chance the new project could lead to cross-platform implementation (Windows and Linux). There is a unit testing support in Visual Studio 2013, but I have no experience with it and how would it fit with the cross-platform.

So far, I have found the [list of unit testing frameworks for C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks#C.2B.2B). However, one cannot see how they differ in principle. I currently have three candidates (conservative choice):

- Boost -- the probable candidate; testbed for C++ standards; hence it is likely it is to be widely accepted; probably the biggest user group. It seems to be more advanced than `CppUnit`.
- CppUnit -- I know it, but it writing all of the code around is not a pleasure.
- Visual Studio 2013 built-in -- new to me, somehow can generate the skeletons probably.

Anyway, it seems that all of the three use similar approach. Possibly the VS2013 supports generating the code, but it does not mean it leads to anything simpler.

Is there any radically new approach?

Comment: The question was completely reworded. Please consider reopen.

Comment: After the years, I still do not agree that this is the off-topic question. The question was completely reworded. in the past, and it apparently attracted some attention. The marked answer names the **Catch** tool, but it contains also comments on **lest**. This way, the answers can be considered "tell me the tool". However, the answer is related to new general approach. Having enough points now, I have voted for reopening.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The only test framework worth considering:
[Catch](http://www.catch-lib.net/)

For an introduction to the lib, see also [here](http://www.levelofindirection.com/journal/2010/12/28/unit-testing-in-c-and-objective-c-just-got-easier.html) and [here](http://www.levelofindirection.com/journal/2013/6/28/catch-10.html)

It's easy to use (a header-only lib consisting of just one header), portable, and has by far the simplest, cleanest syntax of any C++ unit testing framework.

And unlike other libraries, you don't need to remember two dozen different macros f or different types of assertions.

You just use REQUIRE:

```
int one = 1;
REQUIRE( one == 2 );
```

which, through some clever operator overloading, will show both the original expression and the expanded argument values in the output:

```
test.cc(7): FAILED:
  REQUIRE( one == 2 )
with expansion:
  1 == 43
```

Compared to this, every other framework is a chore to use IMO.

I used to use Boost.Test before I found this, but that was *a lot* more cumbersome to set up and use. We use CppUnit at work, and that seems to be designed to be as fragile and painful as possible.

I've looked briefly at the VS2013 test framework, but haven't tried it, and it looks tolerable, but very much like it's emulating "the old guard". It doesn't really try to be cleaner, easier or better than CppUnit, Boost.Test and all the other ones that came before Catch. So I'd say don't bother with it. Tests should be easy to write (and to understand), and Catch is lightyears ahead of every other framework I've seen on that front.

Comment: +1 It is very new to me. I have read the discussion of the author with you and with the others, and it convinced me to give it a try. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @pepr: "I have read the discussion of the author with you and with the others" -- Where? What? Sounds exciting, would appreciate a link, thanks!

Comment: I am not sure but it was probably at Google Groups here https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/catch-forum @jalf, please, can you point it better?

Comment: BTW, let me also say thanks to both of you, for the very nice question, and also for the tip about Catch! _(Is it only me not being all that much surprised to see yet another useful item busted on SO?)_

Comment: C++11 - If you want something very simple (250 LOC), take a look at **[lest](https://github.com/martinmoene/lest)**. It's C++11-specific and based on the same expression decomposition techniques as Catch. There's also a C++03 port.

Comment: Thanks @jalf, I hadn't seen this post before. And just to back Martin up, Lest is veyr much in the spirit of Catch, but without all the C++03 baggage. I didn't know about the C++03 port, though.

Comment: @MartinMoene: Actually, what I like on CATCH is the possibility to use the Behaviour Driven Development (BDD-style). Is it possible with **lest**?

Comment: @philsquared: and others. Please, have a look at https://github.com/pepr/BDDtool It implements a .feature files parser for generating the CATCH skeletons. I have also tried the reverse parser, but it is not done yet. I have other things to do these days.

Comment: @pepr lest provides assertions EXPECT(), EXPECT_THROWS() and EXPECT_THROWS_AS(), that's all. There are 3 variants: lest (no expr decomposing) and lest_decompose, lest_cpp03 (both decomposing expressions as in CATCH). I deliberately kept my lest variants at _a minimum_ to show _a_ C++11 way of testing that was inspired on work by Kevlin Henney, Phil Nash and Andrzej Krzemieński. My hopes are that other people continue from here and create variants they find useful.

Comment: @Martin Is there an easy way to use lest but write your tests across multiple files? All the example code uses `lest::test specification[] = {...}` and then `lest::run( specification, argc, argv );` in main, which doesn't really extend well to defining your `test`s across multiple files.

Comment: @Wallacoloo The gist at https://gist.github.com/martinmoene/59450eaa1371f7c25210 shows how you may use lest with more than one module. I'm considering to add this to lest.hpp. (lest_cpp03 inherently offers this capability through its test registration.)

Comment: @MartinMoene Thanks, and interesting approach! I just spent the evening toying with CATCH and BDD though, and there's no going back for me ;-)

Comment: @Wallacoloo Enjoy ;) Thanks for your remark nonetheless; I added support to write tests across multiple files and related examples.

Comment: [doctest](https://github.com/onqtam/doctest) is my reimplementation of Catch with a huge focus on compilation speed - checkout the [FAQ](https://github.com/onqtam/doctest/blob/master/doc/markdown/faq.md#how-is-doctest-different-from-catch) to see in what ways they are different

Comment: @jalf: As the time flows, and you seems to be interested in testing... Can you look backward, and possibly revisit your answer? Did any better tool (in your opinion) emerged that you are aware of? (Also, would you mind to vote for reopening the question?)

Comment: @onqtam: I have just noticed the existence of your doctest. I did not try, yet. What is the reason for the name "doctest"? Isn't it a bit confusing? (Would you mind to vote for reopening this question by clickin on "reopen" just below the question?)

Comment: @philsquared: Returning back to the topic... Is there any cooperation between you (the Catch author) and the alternative (similar in principle) tools like doctest by onqtam or lest by Martin Moene? (Also, would you mind to vote for reopening this question by clickin on "reopen" just below the question?)

Answer (score 4):

I've been using theVisual Studio 2013 built in test framework for about 6 weeks now and really like it. The integration is excellent and it's very easy to pick up. If you're working on a project that only targets Windows then I thoroughly recommend it.

Comment: The truth is that it will be mainly the Windows project. Anyway, can you guess how difficult would it be to convert it to cross-platform later? Can you compare it with another framework? Is there anything that looks close to the VS framework?

Comment: Except when it doesn't works. For me in VS 2013, I've been trying for 2 days to get it to work with a hello-world DLL. All it gives is cryptic: "Unable to set up test context" errors.

Comment: Generally every time I look at unit testing stuff provided by Microsoft I am left with one overwhelming impression: *they don't know how to do this stuff*!  I say that not as a Microsoft hater, I use Visual Studio all the time and I was an MVP for 10 years.  But seriously, Microsoft's software development culture is rooted in ideas and organizational structure from the 1970s or 1980s at best.  There are tiny little groups inside MS that practice TDD and some semblance of Agile, but it simply isn't in the cultural DNA and that is why their "solutions" for being agile are always off the mark.

Comment: Late addition here (it's now 2015).  I've had huge trouble running my unit tests for 32 bit or 64 bit.  I have distinct build configurations for each but for various reasons it's hard or impossible to select a configuration that covers both (it's one or the other).  It's extremely opaque and almost impossible to configure in this respect.  I'm therefore ditching it for a simpler project/framework where 32/64/C++/CLI bit doesn't get mixed together.

Comment: Just curious...@Sean: 3 years later...are you still using the Visual Studio 2013 build-in test framework? I'm struggling with it as "we speak".