# Test framework for MFC applications

Tags: c++, unit-testing, mfc

I am looking for a test framework for our MFC applications.  I read many Q&As about comparison among the frameworks

- [Comparison of c++ unit test frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242926/comparison-of-c-unit-test-frameworks)
- [Unit testing for C++ code - Tools and methodology](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91384/unit-testing-for-c-code-tools-and-methodology)
- [C++ unit testing framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87794/c-unit-testing-framework)

but can't really see difference for my real purpose, building reliable MFC applications. I would appreciate if anybody who has experience with these frameworks can shed some light.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i've used some of these a little (i mostly use junit). these are very labor intensive - there's no way to automagicaly find and run the tests. you might consider using [nunit](http://www.nunit.org/) and [c++/cli](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++/CLI)

here is one of the c++/cli test examples:

```
// ****************************************************************
// This is free software licensed under the NUnit license. You
// may obtain a copy of the license as well as information regarding
// copyright ownership at http://nunit.org/?p=license&r=2.4.
// ****************************************************************

using namespace NUnit::Framework;
using NUnit::Framework::Is;
using NUnit::Framework::Text;
using NUnit::Framework::List;
using NUnit::Framework::Has;
using System::String;

namespace NUnitSamples
{
    [TestFixture]
    public ref class AssertSyntaxTests : AssertionHelper
    {
    public:
        [Test]
        void IsNull()
        {
            Object ^nada = nullptr;

            // Classic syntax
            Assert::IsNull(nada);

            // Helper syntax
            Assert::That(nada, Is::Null);

            // Inherited syntax
            Expect(nada, Null);
        }

        [Test]
        void IsNotNull()
        {
            // Classic syntax
            Assert::IsNotNull(42);

            // Helper syntax
            Assert::That(42, Is::Not->Null);

            // Inherited syntax
            Expect( 42, Not->Null );
        }

        [Test]
        void IsTrue()
        {
            // Classic syntax
            Assert::IsTrue(2+2==4);

            // Helper syntax
            Assert::That(2+2==4, Is::True);
            Assert::That(2+2==4);

            // Inherited syntax
            Expect(2+2==4, True);
            Expect(2+2==4);
        }

        [Test]
        void IsFalse()
        {
            // Classic syntax
            Assert::IsFalse(2+2==5);

            // Helper syntax
            Assert::That(2+2==5, Is::False);

            // Inherited syntax
            Expect(2+2==5, False);
        }

        [Test]
        void IsNaN()
        {
            double d = double::NaN;
            float f = float::NaN;

            // Classic syntax
            Assert::IsNaN(d);
            Assert::IsNaN(f);

            // Helper syntax
            Assert::That(d, Is::NaN);
            Assert::That(f, Is::NaN);

            // Inherited syntax
            Expect(d, NaN);
            Expect(f, NaN);
        }

        [Test]
        void EmptyStringTests()
        {
            // Classic syntax
            Assert::IsEmpty("");
            Assert::IsNotEmpty("Hello!");

            // Helper syntax
            Assert::That("", Is::Empty);
            Assert::That("Hello!", Is::Not->Empty);

            // Inherited syntax
            Expect("", Empty);
            Expect("Hello!", Not->Empty);
        }

        [Test]
        void EmptyCollectionTests()
        {
            // Classic syntax
            Assert::IsEmpty(gcnew array<bool>(0));
            Assert::IsNotEmpty(gcnew array<int>(3));

            // Helper syntax
            Assert::That(gcnew array<bool>(0), Is::Empty);
            Assert::That(gcnew array<int>(3), Is::Not->Empty);

            // Inherited syntax
            Expect(gcnew array<bool>(0), Empty);
            Expect(gcnew array<int>(3), Not->Empty);
        }

        [Test]
        void ExactTypeTests()
        {
            // Classic syntax workarounds)
            String^ greeting = "Hello";
            Assert::AreEqual(String::typeid, greeting->GetType());
            Assert::AreEqual("System.String", greeting->GetType()->FullName);
            Assert::AreNotEqual(int::typeid, greeting->GetType());
            Assert::AreNotEqual("System.Int32", greeting->GetType()->FullName);

            // Helper syntax
            Assert::That(greeting, Is::TypeOf(String::typeid));
            Assert::That(greeting, Is::Not->TypeOf(int::typeid));

            // Inherited syntax
            Expect( "Hello", TypeOf(String::typeid));
            Expect( "Hello", Not->TypeOf(int::typeid));
        }

        [Test]
        void InstanceOfTypeTests()
        {
            // Classic syntax
            Assert::IsInstanceOfType(String::typeid, "Hello");
            Assert::IsNotInstanceOfType(String::typeid, 5);

            // Helper syntax
            Assert::That("Hello", Is::InstanceOfType(String::typeid));
            Assert::That(5, Is::Not->InstanceOfType(String::typeid));

            // Inherited syntax
            Expect("Hello", InstanceOfType(String::typeid));
            Expect(5, Not->InstanceOfType(String::typeid));
        }

        [Test]
        void AssignableFromTypeTests()
        {
            // Classic syntax
            Assert::IsAssignableFrom(String::typeid, "Hello");
            Assert::IsNotAssignableFrom(String::typeid, 5);

            // Helper syntax
            Assert::That( "Hello", Is::AssignableFrom(String::typeid));
            Assert::That( 5, Is::Not->AssignableFrom(String::typeid));

            // Inherited syntax
            Expect( "Hello", AssignableFrom(String::typeid));
            Expect( 5, Not->AssignableFrom(String::typeid));
        }

        [Test]
        void SubstringTests()
        {
            String^ phrase = "Hello World!";
            array<String^>^ strings = {"abc", "bad", "dba" };

            // Classic Syntax
            StringAssert::Contains("World", phrase);

            // Helper syntax
            Assert::That(phrase, Contains("World"));
            // Only available using new syntax
            Assert::That(phrase, Text::DoesNotContain("goodbye"));
            Assert::That(phrase, Text::Contains("WORLD")->IgnoreCase);
            Assert::That(phrase, Text::DoesNotContain("BYE")->IgnoreCase);
            Assert::That(strings, Text::All->Contains( "b" ) );

            // Inherited syntax
            Expect(phrase, Contains("World"));
            // Only available using new syntax
            Expect(phrase, Not->Contains("goodbye"));
            Expect(phrase, Contains("WORLD")->IgnoreCase);
            Expect(phrase, Not->Contains("BYE")->IgnoreCase);
            Expect(strings, All->Contains("b"));
        }

        [Test]
        void StartsWithTests()
        {
            String^ phrase = "Hello World!";
            array<String^>^ greetings = { "Hello!", "Hi!", "Hola!" };

            // Classic syntax
            StringAssert::StartsWith("Hello", phrase);

            // Helper syntax
            Assert::That(phrase, Text::StartsWith("Hello"));
            // Only available using new syntax
            Assert::That(phrase, Text::DoesNotStartWith("Hi!"));
            Assert::That(phrase, Text::StartsWith("HeLLo")->IgnoreCase);
            Assert::That(phrase, Text::DoesNotStartWith("HI")->IgnoreCase);
            Assert::That(greetings, Text::All->StartsWith("h")->IgnoreCase);

            // Inherited syntax
            Expect(phrase, StartsWith("Hello"));
            // Only available using new syntax
            Expect(phrase, Not->StartsWith("Hi!"));
            Expect(phrase, StartsWith("HeLLo")->IgnoreCase);
            Expect(phrase, Not->StartsWith("HI")->IgnoreCase);
            Expect(greetings, All->StartsWith("h")->IgnoreCase);
        }

        [Test]
        void EndsWithTests()
        {
            String^ phrase = "Hello World!";
            array<String^>^ greetings = { "Hello!", "Hi!", "Hola!" };

            // Classic Syntax
            StringAssert::EndsWith("!", phrase);

            // Helper syntax
            Assert::That(phrase, Text::EndsWith("!"));
            // Only available using new syntax
            Assert::That(phrase, Text::DoesNotEndWith("?"));
            Assert::That(phrase, Text::EndsWith("WORLD!")->IgnoreCase);
            Assert::That(greetings, Text::All->EndsWith("!"));

            // Inherited syntax
            Expect(phrase, EndsWith("!"));
            // Only available using new syntax
            Expect(phrase, Not->EndsWith("?"));
            Expect(phrase, EndsWith("WORLD!")->IgnoreCase);
            Expect(greetings, All->EndsWith("!") );
        }

        [Test]
        void EqualIgnoringCaseTests()
        {
            String^ phrase = "Hello World!";

            // Classic syntax
            StringAssert::AreEqualIgnoringCase("hello world!",phrase);

            // Helper syntax
            Assert::That(phrase, Is::EqualTo("hello world!")->IgnoreCase);
            //Only available using new syntax
            Assert::That(phrase, Is::Not->EqualTo("goodbye world!")->IgnoreCase);
            Assert::That(gcnew array<String^> { "Hello", "World" }, 
                Is::EqualTo(gcnew array<Object^> { "HELLO", "WORLD" })->IgnoreCase);
            Assert::That(gcnew array<String^> {"HELLO", "Hello", "hello" },
                Is::All->EqualTo( "hello" )->IgnoreCase);

            // Inherited syntax
            Expect(phrase, EqualTo("hello world!")->IgnoreCase);
            //Only available using new syntax
            Expect(phrase, Not->EqualTo("goodbye world!")->IgnoreCase);
            Expect(gcnew array<String^> { "Hello", "World" }, 
                EqualTo(gcnew array<Object^> { "HELLO", "WORLD" })->IgnoreCase);
            Expect(gcnew array<String^> {"HELLO", "Hello", "hello" },
                All->EqualTo( "hello" )->IgnoreCase);
        }

        [Test]
        void RegularExpressionTests()
        {
            String^ phrase = "Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.";
            array<String^>^ quotes = { "Never say never", "It's never too late", "Nevermore!" };

            // Classic syntax
            StringAssert::IsMatch( "all good men", phrase );
            StringAssert::IsMatch( "Now.*come", phrase );

            // Helper syntax
            Assert::That( phrase, Text::Matches( "all good men" ) );
            Assert::That( phrase, Text::Matches( "Now.*come" ) );
            // Only available using new syntax
            Assert::That(phrase, Text::DoesNotMatch("all.*men.*good"));
            Assert::That(phrase, Text::Matches("ALL")->IgnoreCase);
            Assert::That(quotes, Text::All->Matches("never")->IgnoreCase);

            // Inherited syntax
            Expect( phrase, Matches( "all good men" ) );
            Expect( phrase, Matches( "Now.*come" ) );
            // Only available using new syntax
            Expect(phrase, Not->Matches("all.*men.*good"));
            Expect(phrase, Matches("ALL")->IgnoreCase);
            Expect(quotes, All->Matches("never")->IgnoreCase);
        }

        [Test]
        void EqualityTests()
        {
            array<int>^ i3 = { 1, 2, 3 };
            array<double>^ d3 = { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 };
            array<int>^ iunequal = { 1, 3, 2 };

            // Classic Syntax
            Assert::AreEqual(4, 2 + 2);
            Assert::AreEqual(i3, d3);
            Assert::AreNotEqual(5, 2 + 2);
            Assert::AreNotEqual(i3, iunequal);

            // Helper syntax
            Assert::That(2 + 2, Is::EqualTo(4));
            Assert::That(2 + 2 == 4);
            Assert::That(i3, Is::EqualTo(d3));
            Assert::That(2 + 2, Is::Not->EqualTo(5));
            Assert::That(i3, Is::Not->EqualTo(iunequal));

            // Inherited syntax
            Expect(2 + 2, EqualTo(4));
            Expect(2 + 2 == 4);
            Expect(i3, EqualTo(d3));
            Expect(2 + 2, Not->EqualTo(5));
            Expect(i3, Not->EqualTo(iunequal));
        }

        [Test]
        void EqualityTestsWithTolerance()
        {
            // CLassic syntax
            Assert::AreEqual(5.0, 4.99, 0.05);
            Assert::AreEqual(5.0F, 4.99F, 0.05F);

            // Helper syntax
            Assert::That(4.99L, Is::EqualTo(5.0L)->Within(0.05L));
            Assert::That(4.99f, Is::EqualTo(5.0f)->Within(0.05f));

            // Inherited syntax
            Expect(4.99L, EqualTo(5.0L)->Within(0.05L));
            Expect(4.99f, EqualTo(5.0f)->Within(0.05f));
        }

        [Test]
        void ComparisonTests()
        {
            // Classic Syntax
            Assert::Greater(7, 3);
            Assert::GreaterOrEqual(7, 3);
            Assert::GreaterOrEqual(7, 7);

            // Helper syntax
            Assert::That(7, Is::GreaterThan(3));
            Assert::That(7, Is::GreaterThanOrEqualTo(3));
            Assert::That(7, Is::AtLeast(3));
            Assert::That(7, Is::GreaterThanOrEqualTo(7));
            Assert::That(7, Is::AtLeast(7));

            // Inherited syntax
            Expect(7, GreaterThan(3));
            Expect(7, GreaterThanOrEqualTo(3));
            Expect(7, AtLeast(3));
            Expect(7, GreaterThanOrEqualTo(7));
            Expect(7, AtLeast(7));

            // Classic syntax
            Assert::Less(3, 7);
            Assert::LessOrEqual(3, 7);
            Assert::LessOrEqual(3, 3);

            // Helper syntax
            Assert::That(3, Is::LessThan(7));
            Assert::That(3, Is::LessThanOrEqualTo(7));
            Assert::That(3, Is::AtMost(7));
            Assert::That(3, Is::LessThanOrEqualTo(3));
            Assert::That(3, Is::AtMost(3));

            // Inherited syntax
            Expect(3, LessThan(7));
            Expect(3, LessThanOrEqualTo(7));
            Expect(3, AtMost(7));
            Expect(3, LessThanOrEqualTo(3));
            Expect(3, AtMost(3));
        }

        [Test]
        void AllItemsTests()
        {
            array<Object^>^ ints = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
            array<Object^>^ strings = { "abc", "bad", "cab", "bad", "dad" };

            // Classic syntax
            CollectionAssert::AllItemsAreNotNull(ints);
            CollectionAssert::AllItemsAreInstancesOfType(ints, int::typeid);
            CollectionAssert::AllItemsAreInstancesOfType(strings, String::typeid);
            CollectionAssert::AllItemsAreUnique(ints);

            // Helper syntax
            Assert::That(ints, Is::All->Not->Null);
            Assert::That(ints, Is::All->InstanceOfType(int::typeid));
            Assert::That(strings, Is::All->InstanceOfType(String::typeid));
            Assert::That(ints, Is::Unique);
            // Only available using new syntax
            Assert::That(strings, Is::Not->Unique);
            Assert::That(ints, Is::All->GreaterThan(0));
            Assert::That(strings, Text::All->Contains( "a" ) );
            Assert::That(strings, Has::Some->StartsWith( "ba" ) );

            // Inherited syntax
            Expect(ints, All->Not->Null);
            Expect(ints, All->InstanceOfType(int::typeid));
            Expect(strings, All->InstanceOfType(String::typeid));
            Expect(ints, Unique);
            // Only available using new syntax
            Expect(strings, Not->Unique);
            Expect(ints, All->GreaterThan(0));
            Expect(strings, All->Contains( "a" ) );
            Expect(strings, Some->StartsWith( "ba" ) );
        }

        [Test]
        void SomeItemsTests()
        {
            array<Object^>^ mixed = { 1, 2, "3", nullptr, "four", 100 };
            array<Object^>^ strings = { "abc", "bad", "cab", "bad", "dad" };

            // Not available using the classic syntax

            // Helper syntax
            Assert::That(mixed, Has::Some->Null);
            Assert::That(mixed, Has::Some->InstanceOfType(int::typeid));
            Assert::That(mixed, Has::Some->InstanceOfType(String::typeid));
            Assert::That(strings, Has::Some->StartsWith( "ba" ) );
            Assert::That(strings, Has::Some->Not->StartsWith( "ba" ) );

            // Inherited syntax
            Expect(mixed, Some->Null);
            Expect(mixed, Some->InstanceOfType(int::typeid));
            Expect(mixed, Some->InstanceOfType(String::typeid));
            Expect(strings, Some->StartsWith( "ba" ) );
            Expect(strings, Some->Not->StartsWith( "ba" ) );
        }

        [Test]
        void NoItemsTests()
        {
            array<Object^>^ ints = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
            array<Object^>^ strings = { "abc", "bad", "cab", "bad", "dad" };

            // Not available using the classic syntax

            // Helper syntax
            Assert::That(ints, Has::None->Null);
            Assert::That(ints, Has::None->InstanceOfType(String::typeid));
            Assert::That(ints, Has::None->GreaterThan(99));
            Assert::That(strings, Has::None->StartsWith( "qu" ) );

            // Inherited syntax
            Expect(ints, None->Null);
            Expect(ints, None->InstanceOfType(String::typeid));
            Expect(ints, None->GreaterThan(99));
            Expect(strings, None->StartsWith( "qu" ) );
        }

        [Test]
        void CollectionContainsTests()
        {
            array<int>^ iarray = { 1, 2, 3 };
            array<String^>^ sarray = { "a", "b", "c" };

            // Classic syntax
            Assert::Contains(3, iarray);
            Assert::Contains("b", sarray);
            CollectionAssert::Contains(iarray, 3);
            CollectionAssert::Contains(sarray, "b");
            CollectionAssert::DoesNotContain(sarray, "x");

            // Helper syntax
            Assert::That(iarray, Has::Member(3));
            Assert::That(sarray, Has::Member("b"));
            Assert::That(sarray, Has::No->Member("x")); // Yuck!
            Assert::That(sarray, !Has::Member("x"));

            // Inherited syntax
            Expect(iarray, Contains(3));
            Expect(sarray, Contains("b"));
            Expect(sarray, Not->Contains("x"));
            Expect(sarray, !Contains("x"));
        }

        [Test]
        void CollectionEquivalenceTests()
        {
            array<int>^ ints1to5 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

            // Classic syntax
            CollectionAssert::AreEquivalent(gcnew array<int> { 2, 1, 4, 3, 5 }, ints1to5);
            CollectionAssert::AreNotEquivalent(gcnew array<int> { 2, 2, 4, 3, 5 }, ints1to5);
            CollectionAssert::AreNotEquivalent(gcnew array<int> { 2, 4, 3, 5 }, ints1to5);
            CollectionAssert::AreNotEquivalent(gcnew array<int> { 2, 2, 1, 1, 4, 3, 5 }, ints1to5);

            // Helper syntax
            Assert::That(gcnew array<int> { 2, 1, 4, 3, 5 }, Is::EquivalentTo(ints1to5));
            Assert::That(gcnew array<int> { 2, 2, 4, 3, 5 }, Is::Not->EquivalentTo(ints1to5));
            Assert::That(gcnew array<int> { 2, 4, 3, 5 }, Is::Not->EquivalentTo(ints1to5));
            Assert::That(gcnew array<int> { 2, 2, 1, 1, 4, 3, 5 }, Is::Not->EquivalentTo(ints1to5));

            // Inherited syntax
            Expect(gcnew array<int> { 2, 1, 4, 3, 5 }, EquivalentTo(ints1to5));
            Expect(gcnew array<int> { 2, 2, 4, 3, 5 }, Not->EquivalentTo(ints1to5));
            Expect(gcnew array<int> { 2, 4, 3, 5 }, Not->EquivalentTo(ints1to5));
            Expect(gcnew array<int> { 2, 2, 1, 1, 4, 3, 5 }, Not->EquivalentTo(ints1to5));
        }

        [Test]
        void SubsetTests()
        {
            array<int>^ ints1to5 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

            // Classic syntax
            CollectionAssert::IsSubsetOf(gcnew array<int> { 1, 3, 5 }, ints1to5);
            CollectionAssert::IsSubsetOf(gcnew array<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, ints1to5);
            CollectionAssert::IsNotSubsetOf(gcnew array<int> { 2, 4, 6 }, ints1to5);
            CollectionAssert::IsNotSubsetOf(gcnew array<int> { 1, 2, 2, 2, 5 }, ints1to5);

            // Helper syntax
            Assert::That(gcnew array<int> { 1, 3, 5 }, Is::SubsetOf(ints1to5));
            Assert::That(gcnew array<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, Is::SubsetOf(ints1to5));
            Assert::That(gcnew array<int> { 2, 4, 6 }, Is::Not->SubsetOf(ints1to5));
            Assert::That(gcnew array<int> { 1, 2, 2, 2, 5 }, Is::Not->SubsetOf(ints1to5));

            // Inherited syntax
            Expect(gcnew array<int> { 1, 3, 5 }, SubsetOf(ints1to5));
            Expect(gcnew array<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, SubsetOf(ints1to5));
            Expect(gcnew array<int> { 2, 4, 6 }, Not->SubsetOf(ints1to5));
            Expect(gcnew array<int> { 1, 2, 2, 2, 5 }, Not->SubsetOf(ints1to5));
        }

        [Test]
        void PropertyTests()
        {
            array<String^>^ strings = { "abc", "bca", "xyz" };

            // Helper syntax
            Assert::That( "Hello", Has::Property("Length")->EqualTo(5) );
            Assert::That( "Hello", Has::Length->EqualTo( 5 ) );
            Assert::That( strings , Has::All->Property( "Length")->EqualTo(3) );
            Assert::That( strings, Has::All->Length->EqualTo( 3 ) );

            // Inherited syntax
            Expect( "Hello", Property("Length")->EqualTo(5) );
            Expect( "Hello", Length->EqualTo( 5 ) );
            Expect( strings, All->Property("Length")->EqualTo(3) );
            Expect( strings, All->Length->EqualTo( 3 ) );
        }

        [Test]
        void NotTests()
        {
            // Not available using the classic syntax

            // Helper syntax
            Assert::That(42, Is::Not->Null);
            Assert::That(42, Is::Not->True);
            Assert::That(42, Is::Not->False);
            Assert::That(2.5, Is::Not->NaN);
            Assert::That(2 + 2, Is::Not->EqualTo(3));
            Assert::That(2 + 2, Is::Not->Not->EqualTo(4));
            Assert::That(2 + 2, Is::Not->Not->Not->EqualTo(5));

            // Inherited syntax
            Expect(42, Not->Null);
            Expect(42, Not->True);
            Expect(42, Not->False);
            Expect(2.5, Not->NaN);
            Expect(2 + 2, Not->EqualTo(3));
            Expect(2 + 2, Not->Not->EqualTo(4));
            Expect(2 + 2, Not->Not->Not->EqualTo(5));
        }

        [Test]
        void NotOperator()
        {
            // The ! operator is only available in the new syntax
            Assert::That(42, !Is::Null);
            // Inherited syntax
            Expect( 42, !Null );
        }

        [Test]
        void AndOperator()
        {
            // The & operator is only available in the new syntax
            Assert::That(7, Is::GreaterThan(5) & Is::LessThan(10));
            // Inherited syntax
            Expect( 7, GreaterThan(5) & LessThan(10));
        }

        [Test]
        void OrOperator()
        {
            // The | operator is only available in the new syntax
            Assert::That(3, Is::LessThan(5) | Is::GreaterThan(10));
            Expect( 3, LessThan(5) | GreaterThan(10));
        }

        [Test]
        void ComplexTests()
        {
            Assert::That(7, Is::Not->Null & Is::Not->LessThan(5) & Is::Not->GreaterThan(10));
            Expect(7, Not->Null & Not->LessThan(5) & Not->GreaterThan(10));

            Assert::That(7, !Is::Null & !Is::LessThan(5) & !Is::GreaterThan(10));
            Expect(7, !Null & !LessThan(5) & !GreaterThan(10));
        }

        // This method contains assertions that should not compile
        // You can check by uncommenting it.
        //void WillNotCompile()
        //{
        //    Assert::That(42, Is::Not);
        //    Assert::That(42, Is::All);
        //    Assert::That(42, Is::Null->Not);
        //    Assert::That(42, Is::Not->Null->GreaterThan(10));
        //    Assert::That(42, Is::GreaterThan(10)->LessThan(99));

        //    object[] c = new object[0];
        //    Assert::That(c, Is::Null->All);
        //    Assert::That(c, Is::Not->All);
        //    Assert::That(c, Is::All->Not);
        //}
    };
}
```

Comment: I thought nunit or c++/cli are for managed code. Our MFC code will not include .NET framework. Are they still possible to run tests for MFC?

Comment: the test classes are written in c++/cli. you can call your regular c++ code from c++/cli. iirc, you must package your app as a dll. i added some sample code from the nunit download. nunit is *almost* the same as junit except that in nunit, a new class is *not* constructed for each test.

Comment: You are right. I have used nunit a lot but haven't thought about that way. I will try it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is very little difference.

I used google test because the docs contain good examples of how to integrate the tests with visual studio and have them run automatically - but the same principles could apply to any of the others

Comment: Good documentation should be one of main factors to choose one, especially for us. Thanks!